# Portability of an executable to another Linux machine

Tags: executable, libraries, dependencies, portability

I've installed the program Motion on one Linux machine (M1) and want the same program on another (M2).

There are various builds of this program, and I have forgotten which one I have used, so can I do a straight copy of the user/bin/motion file from M1 and place it in the user/bin/motion of M2?

I know where the configuration file is, so I'll move that across, but I'm not sure on what video drivers the working version of motion uses on M2; is there any way of finding out?

Is there a way that I can find out its dependencies?

Comment: Just for the record, this is almost always a bad idea. One of Linux's huge advantage over other platforms is package management. Manually copying binaries into system directories circumvents the package manager. In many cases, this just means updating the binary will need to be manual, but in some cases, this can cause system updates significant issues. *TL;DR*: use your package manager.

Comment: Sounds logical, so how would I do this task using dpkg?

Comment: If the package providing the tool you want is truly not available for your OS, then you would create a package for it (it's less difficult than it sounds). Then, you would install the package with dpkg.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Could you make a package from an already installed program?

Comment: No, packaging is a separate process; but learning it is an invaluable skill. It is distro-(or at least package manager)-specific though.

Comment: If one cannot make a package from an already installed program then how is a package manager going to help me duplicate, a working instillation, that I've forgotten where I downloaded it from? I seem to recall that when one installs a program, then a copy of the install file is saved somewhere in the file system, is this correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17779/discussion-between-halosghost-and-reggie).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For moving one program to other computer you have to move:

**1) Executable file**
A simple way to finding commands path is `type` command.

For example: `type cal`

> cal is /usr/bin/cal

**2) Library dependencies**
You can find library dependencies with `ldd` command, But remember if you compiled a program from source the CPU Architecture of both server must be the same.

For example: `ldd date`

> linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff83dff000)
>     librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x0000003784e00000)
>     libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x0000003783e00000)
>     libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x0000003784200000)
>     /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000003783a00000)

**3) Configuration files**
In new server you may need to tell the program to re-create the configuration files because that configuration files belongs to previous server.

**4) Checking hardware dependency**
For checking this I think you have to check program's website for supporting hardwares or you have to test program in new environment.

Comment: How do I find where the executable is stored? I think its in user/bin/ called motion. It runs at machine boot, so could this give me any clues as to where the executable is stored?

Comment: @reggie, `type` command is a simple way.. I edited my post.

Comment: good post. on Centos 6 it had to declare the full path of the executable
 ldd /bin/date
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffd71fa7000)
        librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x00007f9d37fcc000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f9d37c38000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f9d37a1b000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f9d381d4000)